# save class type as Type data type in java

Tags: java, class

I am  trying to save the class type and get it back when required. to save class type i have created one member variable as `Type typeName` in below mentioned class.
but when i try to fetch it back using `getTypeName` its returning `Class` rather than the actual class name.

```
public class Request<T>  {

    private Type typeName;

    public Type getTypeName() {
        return typeName;
    }

    public void setTypeName(Type typeName) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }
}
```

this is how i am saving class type

```
for(Class modelClass: realmObjectClasses) {

        Request<T> request = new Request<T>();
        request.setTypeName(modelClass);            
}
```

now when i am trying to get back the type using `request.getTypeName().getClass()`, method is returning "Class" rather than the actual class type

i need to pass `request.getTypeName().getClass()` value to following constructor `new RequestSerializer(request.getTypeName().getClass())`

```
public RequestSerializer(Class<?> className){

    mClass = className;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `Class` to `Type`. When you call `request.getTypeName().getClass()`, it equals to `modelClass.getClass()`, which is the class of `modelClass`, not `modelClass` itself.

What you need is just a type conversion:

```
new RequestSerializer((Class<?>) request.getTypeName())
```